# Insertar Imagen en exportacion de excel - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, exportar, maatwebsite

Estoy trabajando con laravel 8 y maatwebsite/excel 3.1.29

Estoy realizando una exportacion de un excel, pero debo agregar una imagen por cada fila.
Leí la documentacion y puedo agregar una imagen, a manera de logo. pero necesito agregarla por cada fila:
**Aqui la documentacion:**
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/drawings.html#drawings

Mi excel esta exportando bien, y esta exportando una imagen, como hago para que exporte una imagen por fila?

Este es mi archivo de exportacion?

```
use App\Models\Producto;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithDrawings;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class ProductoExport implements FromCollection,WithHeadings,ShouldAutoSize, WithDrawings
{
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'COD',
            'REF',
            'DESCRIPCION',
            'EMP',
            'PRECIO',
            'FOTO',
        ];
    }

    use Exportable;

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {

        $producto = Producto::select('cod_producto', 'referencia_producto', 'descrip_producto', 'precenta_producto', 'valor_producto', 'ruta_img')
                    ->where('Estado_producto', 'activo' )
                    ->get();

        return $producto;
    }

    public function drawings()
    {
        $drawing = new Drawing();
        $drawing->setName('Logo');
        $drawing->setDescription('This is my logo');
        $drawing->setPath(public_path('/images/facebook.png'));
        $drawing->setHeight(90);
        $drawing->setCoordinates('B3');

        return $drawing;
    }

    
}
```

En la linea donde consulto, producto, el ultimo dato 'ruta_img', me contiene la ruta de la imagen.
que podria hacer?

intenté hacer esto y aunque no me marcó error, y el excel exportó, no hizo nada.

```
public function collection()
    {

        $producto = Producto::select('cod_producto', 'referencia_producto', 'descrip_producto', 'precenta_producto', 'valor_producto', 'ruta_img')
                    ->where('Estado_producto', 'activo' )
                    ->get();

        foreach ($producto as $key => $value) {

            $drawing = new Drawing();
            $drawing->setName('Logo');
            $drawing->setDescription('This is my logo');
            $drawing->setPath(public_path('/images/facebook.png'));
            $drawing->setHeight(90);
            $drawing->setCoordinates('B'.($key+4));
            
        }

        return $producto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Las imágenes que quieras añadir deben salir del método `drawings()`. Cuando las declaras en el método `collection()` la variable nace y muere en el loop. El hecho de asignarles coordenadas no las añade a una eventual planilla.

La documentación de `maatwebsite/excel` explica cómo añadir múltiples imágenes, [devolviendo un array en el método drawings](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/drawings.html#adding-multiple-drawings). En tu caso sería:

```
public function drawings() {
   return $this->collection()->map(function($producto, $index) {
       $drawing = new Drawing();
       $drawing->setPath(public_path($producto->img_path));
       $drawing->setHeight(90);
       $drawing->setCoordinates('B'.($index+3));
       return $drawing;
   })->toArray();
}
```

(no sé si es necesario añadir título y descripción, pero eso lo obtendrías del producto)